# Copy and Paste or append file from excel to word doc

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

ok, so here we go, I have tried to conquer this on my own for the past two days have have tried a lot of solutions.  I am working with data in a Excel Spreadsheet that populates a word file.  The specific problem I have is placing a table at the end of the word document.  I have tried to create the table, and append a word doc that just has the table in it.  nether seems to get done.  My latest attempt was to just use sendkeys to copy and paste the table from the open documents.

I am willing to try anything at this point, short of doing it manually as I have to generate thousands of files.

Stripped code is below:

```
    Option Explicit
    
    Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, DaysSince, FrDays, ToDays As Long
    Dim DocLoc, TagName, TemplName, FileName As String
    Dim TagValue As String
    Dim myData As DataObject
    Dim CurDt As Date
    Dim LastAppDt As Date
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim WordTable As Object
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordContent As Word.Range
    Dim oWorkbookEA As Workbook
    Set oWorkbookEA = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="M:\Form.xlsx")
    Set myData = New DataObject
    Dim oTable As Table
    Dim oCell As Cell
    Dim oPrevRow As Row, oNewRow As Row
    Dim iColumn As Long
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim NoCol As Integer
    Dim NoRow As Integer
    
    
    
    With Sheet1
        DocLoc = "M:\WIP_Rev4.docx" 'Word Document Filename
        
        'Open Word Template
        On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
        Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
        End If
        Set WordTable = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:="M:\Table.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
        
        LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table
            For CustRow = 6 To 7 'LastRow
                    DaysSince = .Range("M" & CustRow).Value
    
                    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                    'For CustCol = 5 To 13 'Move Through 9 Columns
                         TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, 2).Value 'Tag Value
                         With WordDoc.Content.Find
                            .Text = "$Product$"
                            .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                         End With
                        
                            myData.SetText oWorkbookEA.Sheets("Company Info").Shapes("TextBox 6").TextFrame.Characters.Text
                            myData.PutInClipboard
                         With WordDoc.Content.Find
                            .Text = "$VarS$"
                            .Replacement.Text = "^c"
                            .Wrap = wdFindStop
                            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne 'Find & Replace all instances
                         End With
                          myData.SetText oWorkbookEA.Sheets("Company Info").Shapes("TextBox 14").TextFrame.Characters.Text
                            myData.PutInClipboard
                  'This table works fine as it is preexisting       
                         Set oTable = WordDoc.Tables(4)
                        Set oPrevRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.Count)
                        oPrevRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Ingredient Name"
                        oPrevRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = "No."
                        oPrevRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = "Percentage"
                        oTable.Rows.Add
                        Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.Count)
                        oNewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Lidocaine"
                        oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = ""
                        oNewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = Format(.Range("E" & CustRow).Value, "#.#%")
                        oTable.Rows.Add
                        Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.Count)
                        oNewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Glycol"
                        oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = ""
                        oNewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = Format(.Range("F" & CustRow).Value, "#.#%")
                        oTable.Rows.Add
                        Set oNewRow = oTable.Rows(oTable.Rows.Count)
                        oNewRow.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Glycerin"
                        oNewRow.Cells(2).Range.Text = ""
                        oNewRow.Cells(3).Range.Text = Format(.Range("G" & CustRow).Value, "#.#%")
                         'With WordDoc
                         '   .Tables(.Tables.Count).Rows(1).Cells(1).Select
                         '   MsgBox (.Tables.Count)
                         'End With
                         With oTable.Borders
                            .InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                            '.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleDouble
                        End With
                'The begining of my problems
                    WordDoc.Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                    WordTable.Active
                    WordTable.SendKeys ("^a")
                    WordTable.SendKeys ("^c")
                    WordDoc.Active
                    WordDoc.SendKeys ("^v")
    
                    FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("A" & CustRow).Value & "_" & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Last Name & First Name
                    WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                    WordDoc.Close False
            
                    .Range("N" & CustRow).Value = TemplName 'Template Name
                    .Range("O" & CustRow).Value = Now
                 
                    WordDoc.PrintOut
                    WordDoc.Close
            'Kill (FileName) 'Deletes the PDF or Word that was just created
                
            Next CustRow
            WordApp.Quit
    End With
    End Sub
```

Table document is Table.docx that I have tried to append to the end.  That would be my ideal solution.

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: What I've done in the past to prevent myself from having to learn the whole object tree is to create the document I want, then examine it in the "Immediate Pane". That way I can see how/where everything is expected to be in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of copying a table from one document and pasting it at the end of another:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim wd As Word.Application
    Dim docTbl As Word.Document, docMain As Word.Document
    Dim tbl As Word.Table, objRange As Word.Range

    Set wd = GetObject(, "Word.application") 'Word already running with the 2 docs open
    Set docMain = wd.Documents("Document1")
    Set docTbl = wd.Documents("Document2")
    
    Set tbl = docTbl.Tables(1)
    tbl.Range.Copy               '<< copy the table
    
    Set objRange = docMain.Content
    objRange.Collapse Direction:=0  'wdCollapseEnd
    objRange.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    objRange.Collapse Direction:=0
    
    objRange.Paste  '<< paste the table

End Sub
```

FYI I find the `dataobject.putinclipboard` approach pretty unreliable in later versions of Excel, so I'd avoid that if you can.

Comment: I know  have tried this before and had issues with it.  perhaps a syntax snafu, but this worked like a charm.  Thanks!